# adding dollar amounts with jquery in table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has about 5 columns. The last column is named Amount. Say there are 100 records. How do I add up the amounts dynamically...

```
Amount
1. $100.00
2. $25.23
3. $24.00
4. $12.43

Total: $184.43
```

The tricky part here is that the rows can be changed based on a filter. So here's a fake example but say I click on a button that says "Show only even rows" and when clicked it would only show even rows and add the grand total

```
$('.but-even')on('click',function(){
  $('.odd').hide()
})

2. $25.23
4. $12.43

Total: $37.66
```

How do i make it so it always add the column amounts when changes are made? Here's what the table kind of looks like. I'm trying to only add the last columns and make them total at the bottom.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="carrier-broad-view-table" style="table-layout: fixed; min-width: 1405px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 108px;"><col style="width: 194px;"><col style="width: 131px;"><col style="width: 149px;"><col style="width: 172px;"><col style="width: 190px;"><col style="width: 150px;"><col style="width: 151px;"><col style="width: 161px;"></colgroup>

  <thead><tr class="size-row" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 31.5px;"><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="CarrierID" style="height: 31.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Rate Count" style="height: 31.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Rate Amount" style="height: 31.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Payment Count" style="height: 31.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Payment Amount" style="height: 31.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Total Count" style="height: 31.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Total Amount" style="height: 31.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Claim Amount" style="height: 31.5px;"></th></tr></thead><tbody>

    <tr class="all carrierID-3041">
      <td style="text-align:center;">3041</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">73</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$48,997.00</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">14</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$8,277.96</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="viewDetails" data-carrierid="3041">view details <i class="fa fa-arrow-right text-primary fa-xs"></i></a></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">87</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$57,274.96</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="all carrierID-4157">
      <td style="text-align:center;">4157</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">1625</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$660,692.68</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">40</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$21,006.23</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="viewDetails" data-carrierid="4157">view details <i class="fa fa-arrow-right text-primary fa-xs"></i></a></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">1665</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$681,698.91</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="all carrierID-41521">
      <td style="text-align:center;">4157</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">1625</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$660,692.68</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">40</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$21,006.23</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="viewDetails" data-carrierid="4157">view details <i class="fa fa-arrow-right text-primary fa-xs"></i></a></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">1665</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align:center;">$42,692.91</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the HTML table looks like?

Comment: can you put together a small fiddle or show some code

Comment: i added what the table looks like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this on your click event

I have used even call just for testing purpose

```
$('.even').hide()
  var total = 0;
  var oddElements = $('.odd').find('td:last-child');
  console.log(a);
  for(var index = 0; index < oddElements.length; b++)
  {
  total  += parseFloat($(oddElements[index]).text().replace(',','').split("$")[1]);
  }
   + $("#total").text("$"+total);
```

here is a fiddle for it
https://jsfiddle.net/qoy42acd/

Comment: I kind of did a combination between the two responses and added some other code. Afterwards I saw what you did. I'm still having a problem though where the total is not adding. I keep getting a NaN. Here's the code i used. In the code i could see the amount looks right in the console but just doesn't add. if($(this).parent('tr').css('display')=='table-row'){
         curAmount = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(',','').split('$')[1]);
         total += curAmount;
         console.log(curAmount);
       }

Comment: you are adding the amount to a variable "total".. but logging  console.log(curAmount); if this doesn't work can you create a fiddle which will help us understand how you have coded

Comment: turns out i didn't set my total = 0; that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should work (pseudo code as you didn't post your HTML structure);

First a javascript function to collect the table row amount data and set the total amount.

You may have to change the `td` selector to fit with your table. You could use `:nth-child(int)` to select the correct `td`.

```
function setTable() {

   var total;
   $('#myTable tr > td:last-of-type').each(function() {

       total += parseInt(row.innerText.replace('$', ''));
   });

   $('#total').text('Total: $' + total);
}
```

And just make sure to call the function after you modify any rows of the table, like below;

```
$('.but-even')on('click',function(){
    $('.odd').hide()
    setTable();
})
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: finally tried this and i get an error.. here it is: total += parseInt(row.innerText.replace('$', ''));   Also, just to be more specific, i changed #myTable tr > td to #myTable tbody tr > td...